# Silently create a user account when another form is submitted

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, form-alter

I have a form created from another module. I want to add 2 fields to that form: 1. email, 2. password. I think I can do this with hook_form_alter. Then I would like to create a user account and log the user in when the submit button is clicked, then go ahead and execute the action defined by the form.

The original form doesn't have a #submit property...it just has a #action property.

I add the #submit property like this: $form['#submit'] = array('accesscustom_submit');

but accesscustom_submit doesn't seem to be getting called. I think the form is just getting redirected to the #action url that's already defined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to edit the comment form? $form['#action'] is a pretty rare property ... the comment form is the only one I can think of that uses it.

In any case, you can create an account pretty easily by settings up a user array (`$account = array('name' => $username, 'pass' => $pass)`) and sending it to `user_save`. See http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_save/6 for more details.

Once the account is created, you can call `user_external_login` to log them in (http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_external_login/6)

Comment: Hi thank you. I created the user account and that worked nicely. The problem now is '#action' property. Its being called instead of the submit (I was able to create the user account by removing '#action' -just testing, but eventually i need to put it back). So '#action' is being called instead of '#submit'. Is there anyway I can change the order so '#submit' is called first, then '#action'? Thank you!

Comment: You would need to edit the page where #action points, or override the #action with your own page that does the same things plus adds your custom code. What form are you trying to modify? There might be an easier way.

Comment: I'm trying to modify the donations form. it has a url like this: donate/% (where % is replaced by a nodeid of the person to donate to).
so donate/20 is donating to person 20. Its a simple form with the fields: currency and amount. I'm adding username/password/firstname/lastname/email...so I can collect some information on the donor. I tried putting the '#action' inside the '#submit', but that didn't work. thanks for your help.